# IOS App will no longer install via Testflight anymore, what should I do

Tags: ios, testflight, ios-provisioning

I started building an IOS app using the Adobe AIR SDK and packaging for iPad. I used TestFlightApp in order to send users builds and it worked great.

After running into some issues with the AIR SDK I re-coded the app using native objective-c / xcode. I am able to build and test via xcode to my iPad using the same provisioning profile sense I kept the domain of the app the exact same.

I am able to build and IPA and upload it to TestFlight as a new build but users get an error saying they are not allowed to install on their device. I've had them delete the old app and I've tried having them remove and replace the provisioning profile via iTunes. Still get the same error.

Would like some advice on what I should do to get these builds installed and working again.

Answer (score 0):

You probably signed the app with a profile that the users are not a part of. Check your signing process and ensure you are signing with the right profile and that the devices the users registered are part of that profile.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you you give permission to users
Login to TestFlightApp account
Select App to Edit
Select Build to Edit
Click Permissions menu from left side panel
Now select(Check/Uncheck) devices on which you want to allow the installation
And at last click on button "update" or "update and notify"

Comment: I tried that. That didn't seem to fix the issue. I suppose I'll try mccrager suggestion